# Git command to get a non-committed remote changes

Tags: git

Currently, as I learn git (total newbie), I am a one-man show working on a local master repo then pushing changes to a remote master repo after committing and testing. That works great. No one else is involved.

Now, this may sound like madness to the seasoned, but on occasion I've made a quick change to a file directly to files on the server using sFTP, say `myfile.html`

Doing so leaves me in a situation where `myfile.html` on the remote has a change that I need in my local repo. i.e. the remote file is further ahead than my local version. So...

**My question is this:** if a file is modified on the remote via ftp, for example, the change isn't registered by git, so how can I get that change via a Fetch/Pull? If I try now, I'm told that local/remote are up-to-date.

Is there a way to speak to the remote to check if it has any changed files that need staged/committed in the way one can do on a local machine?

If not, is there a way, using git, to compare the files on the local remote so I can at least see the difference and drag my edit back down to my local machine?

Comment: Is there a local Git copy on the server?

Comment: Chris, there is a .git folder, along with .gitignore and .gitattributes - is that what you mean? I'm running the site on WP-Engine hosting if that helps.

Comment: There is no terminal access to the server though.

Comment: Oh, so it's Platform as a Service, like Heroku? You `git push` and the service spins up your site automatically?

Comment: Exactly. I'm interested to know the answer to the above in a more general way too, but, yes, for this instance that's exactly what happens. It's very like FTP - you hit Push and it deploys to the Production server.

Comment: In general, PaaS providers do not provide a mechanism to clone or fetch from the deployed site, and I wouldn't expect them to. They're not in the business of repository hosting. Heroku [does let users clone](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app) (and, presumably, fetch), but only as a convenience. I can't speak about WP Engine. Maybe you should ask their tech support folks?

Comment: Thanks Chris, that clarifies a lot. I didn't know there was a distinction.

So, if I was on a non-PaaS system then what I mentioned would be possible? I assume this would be a server with git installed and running on it? Would you then terminal in as a user on the server, check for unstaged changes and commit just like on a local machine?

Comment: For anyone else using WP-Engine, they are "Git Push" only. Read bout it here: http://bit.ly/VLr1sD and related to my question, they say: "*Git is a one-way versioning tool. That means any changes you make to your file system through a web interface or via SFTP will not propagate back into Git. This is why we recommend setting up a local dev environment and making all code changes there and pushing those changes to your app through Git. Read more about setting up a local development environment*"

Comment: Regarding non-PaaS systems, in general, yes. There are a few details that might be relevant, but that's not likely important at the moment. Regarding your solution comment, please consider posting this as an answer below. You should be able to accept it in a couple of days.

Comment: @Chris - done. if you could check it's accurate, I'd appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris)'s advice, I'm posting this answer.

Git is sometimes hosted as Platform as a Service (like Heroku or, in my case, WP-Engine's "Git Push").

Often these installs are basically one-way streets. The idea is that you create a local or distributed git dev environment then Push your files to them when tested. So git push here is a bit like sFTP in that the files go straight to the Production environment (you could be using a staging server too, of course).

However, if a user creates or edits a file directly via FTP or through a web interface, it will not be available to stage and commit using this type of system. When you git pull/fetch you'll be told your files are up to date even though they aren't because there is no difference between what git sees on the server and in your repo.

In short, in such platforms, git doesn't watch out for what you do outside of git.

If you have made remote changes via sFTP then download them via sFTP to your local install to update the local file, then stage and commit it back up so it enters the repo.

On other platforms, like Github, the environment is controlled so you can only change files via methods that git is aware of. So you're not going to create files that are outside of git's awareness.

Finally, if you're running git on your own (or hosted) server, you could "more or less" (I'm not an expert) terminal in as a user on the server, check for unstaged changes and commit just like on a local machine. If you need to do that, I'm sure the experts on this forum can help.